# How i can show all Posts in Tumblr Other than Home Page

Tags: tumblr

Is there a way that i can show all posts other than Home Page.. I have Made Home page as Static Page. But i am Unable to get All posts on My BLOG page in Tumblr.
Is there a way..
Or
If there is a method to get Posts of All tags.

Comment: @Muhammed-Baber-Zama do you have a link to your tumblr?

Answer (score 1):

If you tag your posts with a common tag you can then create a link to those by making a new page (in the page options instead of Standard layout, choose Redirect).

Then for the redirect rule you can use something like:

```
/tagged/news
```

Or whatever tag you want. This will return all posts tagged with 'News' on your blog.

More information here: 
https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/pages#redirect